# Datatables FixedColumns IE8/7 Firefox error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm having some problems with the FixedColumn plugin in IE8, IE7 and Firefox.

All of them "destroying my table". This is the error that they return.

```
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 566
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: ./resources/javascript/dataTable/FixedColumns.js
```

The table is getting away from its place. Here is 2 images that shows what is happening with the table.
[image: The tables is misplaced]

[image: The tables is misplace]

Can you guys help me? I've been searching in Datatable forums and Google and didn't found anything that helped me.

Envoirnment:

1. Jquery 1.8.1
2. Datatables 1.9.3
3. FixedColumn 2.0.3

Regards,
Elkas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did, in my case, I've loaded all the days of the month i was checking, putting the days ahead of today at white

I think the plugin don't work properly with IE with one static column and the others not static.

The Browser, IE8 in this case, was processing the documents as IE7, so i had to add a meta tag to force it to render it as IE8 documents.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SetMode) to the description of that issue.